# Disable auto deleting profiles Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

when i am doing all the stuff and want to close `WebDriver` with `WebDriver.Close()` method, it closes everything and it also deletes temp Firefox profile. How i can disable it?

I tried to open Directory as process so program was be unable to delete it but it didnt work as i expected.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse Firefox profiles between instances of Web Driver?